# How to pair events from different recordings?

Tags: math, optimization

I have what I think to be an optimization problem that I have already solved. I think, however, that there might be a more robust solution which I don't quite know how to implement. Maybe someone here has some ideas.

#### Problem Description

I need to pair events from two separate recordings. An event has a name, a time **t** at which it occurred and an amplitude **a** with the constraint that the next event occurs at **t_next** = **t** + **a**. The two recordings should produce events at the same time and amplitude, but there are recording errors to deal with like drift.
The task is to group the same events into pairs of 2.
Here is an example:

```
Event Name  t           a           t           a
39770       155648.16   41.96       154726.4    41.75
39780       155690.12   42.01       154768.15   41.78
39790       155732.13   41.24       154809.94   41.13
39800                               154851.06   5.74
39810       155773.37   1.55            
39815       155774.03   1.55            
39820       155774.92   3.75            
39830       155778.67   0.65            
39840       155779.32   22.35       154856.81   22.24
39850       155801.67   1.36        154879.04   1.27
39855       155802.4    1.36        154879.66   1.27
39860       155803.04   12.79       154880.31   12.74
```

As you can see, the **t** and **a** values are not exactly the same within a pair (same row), so I have to work with tolerances. Sometimes, you have events in recording 1 what you don't have in recording 2 and vice verse. So how can I pair them?

#### Idea For Solution

I was thinking of a "rubberband" approach somehow. Basically, you group the events by amplitude within the allowed tolerance such that you maximize the number of paired up events. But I'm not sure how to deal with missing events in one recording vs the other. Somehow, I have to ignore them and I'm not sure how to best do that without this problem exploding due to exorbitant combinations to try.

Has anyone come across this kind of problem and knows a robust solution for it?

Comment: [This article](https://nicoschertler.wordpress.com/2014/06/13/matching-error-prone-sequences-of-numbers-e-g-time-codes-to-each-other/) might be helpful. It does only consider the time stamps, though (disregarding the amplitude).

Comment: @Nico Thank you, I will take a look.

Comment: @Nico, do you happen to have the code somewhere? I tried downloading the VS2012 code, but the code isn't there anymore.

Comment: The link in the article should work. [Here is a direct link](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AgXl9vuHCSIOgpZnD1BmFEcxI8QqlQ).